# How to get remaining records which we can't fetch through Single API call in Zoho Creator?

Tags: zoho, zohobooks

I am fetching data from Zoho Books to Zoho Creator using getRecords() but I am able to fetch only 200 records.
How can I fetch the remaining records (Suppose I have 300 records, through first call I got 200 records, How to fetch the remaining 100 records)?

Answer (score 1):

```
resp=zoho.books.getRecords("invoices", "org_id","page=4");
has_more_page=resp.get("page_context").getJSON("has_more_page");
info has_more_page;
```

has_more_page will return true if more record are available